# Why does the compiler think this is an Object instead of a DataRow?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, casting, option-strict

I'm using a LINQ query to translate data inside a `DataTable` object to be a simple `IEnumerable` of a custom POCO object.

My LINQ query is:

```
    Dim dtMessages As DataTable

    '...dtMessages is instantiated ByRef in a helper data access routine... '

    Dim qry = From dr As DataRow In dtMessages.Rows
              Select New OutboxMsg With {
                  .ComputerID = dr(dcComputerID),
                  .MessageData = dr(dcMessageData),
                  .OutBoxID = dr(dcOutBoxID),
                  .OutBoxReceivedID = dr(dcOutBoxReceivedID),
                  .TrxDate = dr(dcTrxDate)
              }
```

However, the compiler is throwing a warning message under `dr As DataRow` with the message:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Why am I getting this error and what do I need to do to fix it?  I would have thought that `dtMessages.Rows` returned a collection of type `DataRow`. Is this not correct?

Comment: Show how dtMessages is declared and instantiated.

Comment: @bzlm I updated my post with more info

Comment: Just turn off `Option Strict`!  I kid, I kid.

Comment: @Marc He should turn off VB.NET instead. :)

Comment: @bzlm Although I generally prefer C# to VB.NET, I get paid to write code in VB.NET, so it would be a very expensive decision to throw it away :-).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lok at `DataTable.Rows` - it's a `DataRowCollection` which only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)`.

Fortunately, there's an extension method in [`DataTableExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.aspx) which lets you call [`AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) instead of `Rows`; `AsEnumerable` returns an `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)`:

```
Dim qry = From dr As DataRow In dtMessages.AsEnumerable()
          ...
```

(I prefer this over using `dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)`, as it gives less of an impression of something which *might* fail. It's more tailored to `DataTable`. Both will work though.)

Answer (score 8):

The type `System.DataTable` predates generics in .Net and hence returns a plain old `IEnumerable` instead of an `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)` even though under the hood they are instances of `DataRow`.  Hence the type of `dr` in the above query is `Object` and not `DataRow`.

You can work around this by using the `Cast` extension method to make the type of the collection explicit

```
From dr As DataRow in dtMessages.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `DataTable.Rows` property returns a collection of `DataRow`, however that collection doesn't implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>` but `IEnumerable`, which works as `IEnumerable<Object>`.

You can explicitly cast the collection items to `DataRow` using `dtMessages.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()`.